# how can I use this library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I don't know how to add this library to my project.

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

thank you.

**Edit :** can anyone explain how to open the sample app as an android project?

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/tree/develop/sample

Comment: There is steps how to use it. https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle(app:module)` add this line in the dependencies block:

```
implementation 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

and follow instruction according to the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

On your file gradle insert into dependencies paste this `compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'`

Example:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'

}
```

Then click sync now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside module build.gradle file

**compile "com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6**"

Now sync gradle file and library will be added into project now you can follow instructions on github about calendar customization and settings